# Trie that accept any python object as value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there readily available trie implementation that could support any python object (instantiation from a python class) as a value?

e.g.

```
Trie[key]= MyOwnClass(..)
```

?

Comment: i think `Trie` is a prefix tree (trie) implementation. so he need to explain more about the class !

Comment: Do you mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie or do you mean a normal tree?

Comment: @VincentBeltman yes, i mean the wikipedia one.

Comment: @Tichodroma you can refer to the wikipedia as posted above :)

Comment: I think the answer below is a good solution. Last year i made a generic Trie in Java, so it is possible.